# Script to generate test users with random data for Facebook application

Tags: facebook, testing

I want to test my Facebook application with the maximum 500 test users available.  I've had a go at using the interface which facebook provide and another good one called "FacebookTestUserManager", but these create blank user profiles and I want to populate certain parts of the profiles with random information e.g. profile picture, education etc.

I don't think getting this data should be too difficult (I'm thinking a list of options and getting a random number generator to select a choice), but I'm confused as to how I input this information into the accounts and how I run my script.

This http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ is basically the only resource I can find on the matter, but it is very brief.  My questions are:

**1)  Before I start, are there are any public scripts which already do this?**

**2)  How do I run my script which does this account generation process?  I presume it's not written inside my application since I only want it run once!**

Answer (score 0):

> How do I run my script which does this account generation process?

Like you run any other script …

> I presume it's not written inside my application since I only want it run once!

It does not have to be “inside” of anything, it just has to use your app access token while doing it’s Graph API calls.

---

*I think all of what the document you referred to says should be easily understandable to a developer with a solid basic knowledge about how apps and their interactions with the Grapf API work. Should you not have such knowledge yet … then I don’t see any use in testing an app with 500 test users already.*

Comment: Ok maybe 500 test users is excessive, but the point is that I don't want to waste time manually inputting profile data if there is a way that I can input it programmatically.  Do you know if there is a way?  I assume that those who do require 500 users do not input manually..

Comment: The docs page you linked mentioned what way there is to create test users and which data can be changed via API.